# X-Frame-Options Deny not working at all

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, http-headers, web-config

i tried many ways to deny  `X-Frame-Options` for disable to load iframe from my website but no success.

**via http header:**

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">
```

**javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( window.self !== window.top ) {
    window.top.location.href=window.location.href;
}
</script>
```

**web.config:**

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

none of these working, so the question is what is the best solution? and why these not working on my website? *(**note:** i can not access to IIS directly, just can edit web.config or add some code to website)*

<kbd>*ASP.net VB.net - IIS*</kbd>

Comment: How are you setting the web.config - and is the header actually set when you inspect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want prevent it site-wise then just add a header in your global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
}
```

If you want to do it on specific request/response then

```
Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
```